# Zenith Angle for DNI calculation

Tags: python, pvlib

For a machine learning problem, I want to derive the hourly PV power of a specific system given various weather parameter, including hourly GHI and DHI, but no DNI. If I would take one of the [pvLib DNI estimation models](https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#dni-estimation-models), I always need the zenith angle. Since I have hourly values for Irradiance, I cannot be very specific regarding the angle. Would you take an hourly average? There is always the problem that angles close to 90° result in super high DNI values.

So far I tried to manually calculate hourly DNI = (GHI-DHI)/cos(zenith), taking the mean of 5 min resolution zenith angles for the hourly zenith. The sunrise in the location is almost always before 7 am, so I should get some very small PV power in hour 6 of the day. However, due to the fact that I take the average which is almost always over 90°, I get 0 kW AC power or for the few days when the mean angle is just below 90° I get 40 kW AC power, which is the system's maximum limited by the inverters and this in these early hours even more unrealistic.

ModelChain Parameters:

```
pvsys_ref=pvsyst
loc_ref=loc
orient_strat_ref=None
sky_mod_ref='ineichen'
transp_mod_ref='haydavies'
sol_pos_mod_ref='nrel_numpy'
airm_mod_ref='kastenyoung1989'
dc_mod_ref='cec'
ac_mod_ref=None
aoi_mod_ref='physical'
spec_mod_ref='no_loss'
temp_mod_ref='sapm'
loss_mod_ref='no_loss'
```

The required weather panda consists out of the hourly simulated ghi, dhi, temp and windspeed as well as the manually calculated dni.

Comment: Did the answer help you?

Comment: Hey @adr, thanks for your help!
I will test it today, but I assume that the results, compared to my manual approach won't vary much as when checking the source code, they use the same equation :)
I will let you know.

Answer (score 0):

Usually the midpoint of the hour is used to calculate the sun position/sun zenith, and for the sunset and sunrise hours, the midpoint of the period when the sun is above the horizon.

To calculate DNI from GHI and DHI, try using the function `dni` in `pvlib.irradiance`:

https://pvlib-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generated/pvlib.irradiance.dni.html#pvlib.irradiance.dni

Comment: Thanks for your help @adr again, as already expected in the comment above, it results in exactly the same value as when applying the equation mentioned in my description, as it is the one used in the dni function of irradiance, too.  However, I will try to use the midpoint technique! Thanks for that.